# Spark MLLib LogisticRegression debug model?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm working on a LogisticRegression model and trying to debug.

It's a simple thing but can't seem to get it to work: just have `time of day` and a `state 0 or 1`, and want to predict the state for a given time of day.

There are no errors when training the model, but I see this:
`GradientDescent: GradientDescent.runMiniBatchSGD finished. Last 10 stochastic losses NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN`

in the logs
when trying to `eval` I always end up with an error `java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: keyname`

I have seen this before when feeding the classifier a feature set that is not possible, but here I am only using 1 feature and it's a simple model, so I don't understand what is wrong.

Any idea how I can see what is going on?

I also used `BinaryClassificationMetrics` and it returns

`FmeasureCurve` = `(NaN,0.17630133869823753)`

`ROCCurve` =

`(0.0,0.0)
(1.0,1.0)
(1.0,1.0)`

How would I print the model information to see what values are in there?
I there an easy way to get this data?

When I print the model I only get: 
`org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel: intercept = 0.0, numFeatures = 1, numClasses = 2, threshold = None`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's going on. A few ideas: (1) Copy your data set into your question. (2) Make sure that 0 and 1 cases are interspersed in your data (i.e. there is no hard cut-off in your input space). That ensures that the parameters are some finite values. (3) Call `clearThreshold` on your model, then `predict` will yield raw (probabilistic) outputs. (4) There is a way to get the fitted parameters, I forget how. My only advice on this point is to browse the code and try to see how to return the parameters.

Comment: I guess the problems was that there was not just one fitted peak in the data but multiple and that didn't work well. I ended up using a different algorithm.